# How to correctly re-send other notification in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm struggling to deal with the Android Notification system. I want to get all active notifications in the status bar for which I used `manager.getActiveNotifications();` to get all the `StatusBarNotification`, but the main problem is that I want to re-send (or duplicate) that exact notification with the exact title, description, additional info (Bundle) it holds and send from the exact channel it has been sent from (if possible).

The reason for this is that I noticed some apps have a notification that a pop-up or something appears when the user clicks on it. I want my app to get that notification first to dupe the notification and then, if possible, store it like a shortcut so I can access it easily.

Thank you in advance for any help.